# Using System.currentTimeMillis() to get time on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I've being using System.currentTimeMillis() to get the current time of an action occuring in my Android activity. The time it gives when converted to a date something like this Thu 20 January 1970 20:15. I am wondering if this is just because I am using it on the emulator of is there something gone wrong?

EDIT:

```
 times = System.currentTimeMillis();

 //Converting to Date using constructor Date(long milliseconds)
 Date changeToDate = new Date(times);
```

Comment: What is the time settings on emulator.

Comment: how are you calculating date from System.currentTimeMillis(), write code

Comment: The time on the emulator is Fri Feb 10 10:16:12 GMT 2012 which is my local time give or take few seconds

Answer (score 0):

It's just a guess: you probably convert millis to date incorrectly. Don't you divide them by 1000 while passing to `Date` constructor?

Answer (score 0):

which `Date` class did you import in your project? probably you have imported `java.sql.Date` but the one which you should use is `java.util.Date` - perhaps this helps a little bit.. @a.ch. : `java.util.Date` needs milliseconds, not seconds (ms/1000) in its constructor ;)

Comment: java.util.Date. It should work but can't figure out why it won't